# Android - Calling RecyclerView in Fragment of Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-drawer

My trouble is when I want to call `RecyclerView` into `Fragment` of `NavigationDrawer` and items (arrays) that I call via `RecyclerView` not called, but when I do not put into `Fragment` it could be called. So Here is my code.

Here is my `Fragment.java` and it says error on `recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);`

```
public class fragment_1bakso extends Fragment {

private AppCompatActivity compat;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private MakananAdapter adapter;
public fragment_1bakso() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

ArrayList<Makanan> mList = new ArrayList<>();
MakananAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    /*View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1bakso, container, false);
    return v;*/
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_calling, container, false);
    return rootview;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //mClass.setContentView(R.layout.activity_calling);
    //return new fragment_1bakso(R.layout.activity_calling, this);


    GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    mAdapter = new MakananAdapter(mList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    fillData();
}

private void fillData() {
    Resources resources = getResources();
    String [] arJudul = resources.getStringArray(R.array.bakso);
    String [] arHarga = resources.getStringArray(R.array.bakso_price);
    String [] arDeskripsi = resources.getStringArray(R.array.bakso_desc);
    String [] arLokasi = resources.getStringArray(R.array.bakso_locations);
    String [] arDetail = resources.getStringArray(R.array.bakso_details);
    TypedArray a = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.bakso_pict);
    Drawable[] arFoto = new Drawable[a.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < arFoto.length; i++)
    {
        arFoto[i] = a.getDrawable(i);
    }
    a.recycle();

    for (int i = 0; i < arJudul.length; i++)
    {
        mList.add(new Makanan(arJudul[i],arHarga[i],arFoto[i],arDeskripsi[i],arDetail[i],arLokasi[i]));
    }
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}}
```

Here is my `Fragment.xml`

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="id.sch.smktelkom_mlg.learn.sideview.fragment_1bakso">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <include
        layout="@layout/activity_calling"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Here is my `Activity_calling.xml` that used to call the item in array (RecyclerView)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    tools:context="id.sch.smktelkom_mlg.learn.sideview.activity_1bakso" />
```

Help me guys, thanks in advance.

Comment: try changing GridLayoutManager with LinearLayoutManager

Comment: move your code from `onCreate()` to `onViewCreated()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't initialized your recyclerView.

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.your_id);
```

Also move the code from onCreate() to onViewCreated();

Answer (score 0):

If you need grid layout manager you can try this out

```
GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 1);
```

Or you can go for a horizontal linear layout manager like so

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
```

Or you can go for a vertical linear layout manager like so

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
```

Comment: it says cannot be applied into `this`

Answer (score 0):

```
final RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager =new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 1);
    recyclerView_drawer.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView_drawer.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView_drawer.setAdapter(drawerAdapter);
```

Hope this code will help you.you can replace frame layout with Relative Layout also,as you said in frame layout its not working.

Comment: but what is in the recyclerview_drawer ?

Comment: recyclerView_drawer is my Recyclerview object for you its a recyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

You did not initialise your recyclerview which can be done as :

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
```

And define grid layout manager as :

```
 GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
    recyclerView .setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView .setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView .setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

And yes move your code from onCreate to onViewCreated as :

```
 @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}
```

Hope it helps.. happy coding :)